# callback for tabnavigator tab press or tab swipe react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

Is there any way to call a function upon each TAB switch either via TabPress /Tab Swipe Event.

For tabPress I have tried **tabBarOnPress** in **navigationOptions** of TabNavigator and it is working fine.But it is not getting called if I **swipe** between different tabs.

If anyone has any idea about "**tabBarOnSwipe**" like  event within tabnavigator of react-navigation please let me know.

Comment: did you find the solution already?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?